# A slice over slices?

Tags: rust

I'm trying to use a third-party library in Rust that accepts only &[u8] as input. The actual input I'd like to supply exists as a bunch of separate arrays of u8.

Is it possible to create something that looks like a &[u8] but actually fetches the data from my underlying &[u8]s?

I'm new to Rust and may be having some conceptual difficulties, but this looks like an interface to me (https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html), and in other languages I can implement interfaces using arbitrary code. Can I do it in this case?

Comment: If I understand properly, you could have two slices `a` and `b`, and want to make one bigger slice with the content of `a` followed by the content of `b`? Then no, it's not possible without making a whole new array/vector. A slice must be continuous in memory.

Comment: it's not possible if the API want a slice. This would need a trait.

Answer (score 5):

A slice type `[T]` for some `T` is a concrete type, not an interface/trait, and a slice has to be a contiguous region of memory. You can [concatenate](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.concat) slices into some container by copying their contents:

```rust
let a: &[u8] = &[1, 2, 3];
let b: &[u8] = &[4, 5];

foo(&[a, b].concat())
```

If you can’t do that, barring memory mapping hacks (not accessible to safe Rust), the library would need to be changed to accept something more general.